# Exponentiation on a proof by induction

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-explanation, exponentiation

I am beginning to learn about proofs by induction, but cant get my head around the steps taken in a slide we've been shown.[image]

My problem lies within the red box, and I'm not sure if I'm missing some very basic math here.
Particularly, between lines 2 and 3 of the red box:

$$3^{2k} 3^2 \text{ becomes } 8 \cdot 3^{2k}$$

How does this happen? I presume the answer is trivial but I don't want to skip over it.

Comment: $9=8+1$. They are just splitting the first term into two parts.

Comment: @ScottAdamson Please type out what is in the image using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/29979#29979).

Comment: Is $P(k)$ a proposition, or is it a number?

Answer (score 1):

$3^2 = 9 = 8 + 1$, so:

$$3^{2k} 3^2 + 11$$
$$= 3^{2k} (8 + 1) + 11 $$
$$= 3^{2k} \cdot 8 + 3^{2k} \cdot 1 + 11 \tag{distributive law}$$
$$= 8 \cdot 3^{2k} + 3^{2k} + 11.$$

Answer (score 0):

See also [rules for exponentiation](https://mathinsight.org/exponentiation_basic_rules).

We have $$P(k+1)=3^{2(k+1)}+11$$
$$=3^{2k+2}+11$$
$$=3^{2k}3^{2}+11$$
$$=9\cdot3^{2k}+11$$
$$=(8+1)\cdot3^{2k}+11$$
$$=8\cdot3^{2k}+3^{2k}+11$$
$$=4(2\cdot3^{2k})+3^{2k}+11.$$